# java explicit type conversion gives different results

Tags: java, type-conversion, explicit, promotions

I would like to know in which **order** does the explicit type conversion work and in what **area** does it work. In the next example I receive different results.

```
float S = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (int j = 3; j <= 20; j++)
        S += (i * j - 5.)/(2. * i + j / 3);
```

the result is 621.8933

```
float S = 0;
for (float i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (float j = 3; j <= 20; j++)
        S += (i * j - 5)/(2. * i + j / 3);
```

S = 607.3105

```
float S = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (int j = 3; j <= 20; j++)
        S += (float)(i * j - 5)/(2 * i + j / 3);
```

S = 621.8933

```
float S = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (int j = 3; j <= 20; j++)
        S += (i * j - 5)/(2 * i + j / 3.);
```

S = 607.3105

Obviously the correct result is 607.3105. Why doesn't it promote when I write (float) or multiply by 2., but it works when I divide by 3.? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are casting the result of `(i * j - 5)/(2 * i + j / 3)` to a `float`. This is too late - truncation has already occurred. You need the promotion before any `int` arithmetic that could cause truncation.

Comment: Let's take the first example, where I have (2. * i + j / 3). I thought at first it will multiply i by number of type double, after that divide and add. So at least in these brackets it should have been automatically promoted to type double. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `j/3` has precedence over `+` and `j` is an `int`...

Comment: OK. I thought everything in brackets will automatically promote after multiplication. But it means only two operands can promote.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 `S += (i * j - 5.)/(2. * i + j / 3);`:

- `j` is an `int`, thus complete divisor is `int` and an implicit cast to int  is performed

Code 2 `S += (i * j - 5)/(2. * i + j / 3);`

- `j`, `x` are floats and all consecutive results are floats too

Code 3 `S += (float)(i * j - 5)/(2 * i + j / 3);`

- `j` is an `int`, thus complete divisor is `int` and an implicit cast to int is performed
- The explicit `float`- is performed after computing of the divisor

Code 4 `S += (i * j - 5)/(2 * i + j / 3.);`

- Due to '3.' the divisor becomes of type 'double'

Note that `3.` is a double, `3.f` is a float. This results in usage of different precision within the operation.